# Add shortcode to storefront header action

Tags: wordpress, hook-woocommerce, storefront

I'm trying to add a shortcode to the header in a Wordpress Woocommerce site that uses the Storefront theme.

The code that executes the content is...

```
do_action( 'storefront_header' );
```

And I'm trying to add the shortcode by using this in the functions.php file...

```
add_action( 'storefront_header', 'bkb_storefront_header_content', 40 );
function bkb_storefront_header_content() {
    echo do_shortcode('[lsphe-header]');
}
```

I also tried to echo out a piece of text, but this did not work either...

```
add_action( 'storefront_header', 'bkb_storefront_header_content', 40 );
function bkb_storefront_header_content() {
    echo "HERE";
}
```

Comment: It is working fine in my case. Can you enable the WP_DEBUG and check what is the error.

Comment: Try with priority 70, `add_action( 'storefront_header', 'bkb_storefront_header_content', 70 );`

Comment: @Mohandes After priority 70, it is showing below the menu.

Comment: Where you want it to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Storefront has the following sections hooked with the `storefront_header` action:

```
storefront_header
@hooked ‘storefront_skip_links’, 0
@hooked ‘storefront_social_icons’, 10
@hooked ‘storefront_site_branding’, 20
@hooked ‘storefront_secondary_navigation’, 30
@hooked ‘storefront_product_search’, 40
@hooked ‘storefront_primary_navigation’, 50
@hooked ‘storefront_header_cart’, 60
```

set the higher priority depending on where you want to show your shortcode.
If you would like to replace a section with your shortcode content, first remove the default storefront action then add your new action:
for example to replace the social icons with your shortcode content add this code:

```
remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_social_icons', 10 );
add_action( 'storefront_header', 'bkb_storefront_header_content', 11 );
```

More: https://businessbloomer.com/storefront-theme-visual-hook-guide/

Comment: I'm not able to see any change from the removing and adding of actions, I'm now using this...`remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_secondary_navigation', 30 );
add_action( 'storefront_header', 'bkb_storefront_header_content', 31 );
function bkb_storefront_header_content() {
 echo do_shortcode('[lsphe-header]');
 echo "HERE"; 
}`, neither the result of the shortcode nor the "HERE," regardless of the priority level. where

Comment: I'm trying to replace the "Login" link in the purple box in the header... the 'storefront_secondary_navigation' area. Not seeing any change removing and adding actions like...`remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_secondary_navigation', 30 );
add_action( 'storefront_header', 'bkb_storefront_header_content', 31 );
function bkb_storefront_header_content() {
 echo do_shortcode('[lsphe-header]');
 echo "HERE"; 
}`Even just using `remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_secondary_navigation', 30 );` does not eliminate the "Login" link in the purple header box.